# How to apply excel formula to selected columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

This is my table in excel. What I'm trying to do is to multiply the constant rate with funding a and funding b and then getting the difference between the product of the two in the difference column. I need to do this for the next 50 years in the excel table for each funding type. Is there a way i can do this without having to do it manually for each column?

```
+------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------+
| funding a(year1) |     rate      | funding b(year1) |     difference     | funding a(year2) | funding b(year2) | difference |
+------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------+
| Value            | constant rate | value2           | fundingb -fundinga |                  |                  |            |
| value            | constant rate | value2           |                    |                  |                  |            |
| value            | constant rate | value2           |                    |                  |                  |            |
+------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------+
```

Comment: If you use Power Query (Get Data) you can get this done. But you need to refresh every time some data changes.

Comment: Put your data into a Table (List Object) and enter your formulas in the first row.  The Table will then populate the formulas for you through the whole table - even when you add a row.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
select the range, and `ctrl+G` to call locating, select `blank` cell.
move your cursor to formula region, type the formula`=$A$2*(C2-B2)`, then press `ctrl+enter`.
Done.
demo as below.
[image]

Comment: Except that he would have to do that for every entry. Not a solution that most people would find acceptable.

Comment: no, just set  once. As there is 50 years  data, he just wants to aviod input formula one by one manully and repeatly. because  formula  cannot  be  dragged  here.